# How to formally describe this experimental design?

Tags: experiment-design, survey

Apologies if this is a little off-topic for a stats forum, but I don't know where else I could pose my question online and I'm positive that many contributors here would be able to easily answer my question.

Basically, I conducted an experiment but now I'm unsure of how to formally describe the experimental design I employed. I'll try to describe in fairly lay terms how the experiment was structured, and hopefully one of you knowledgeable sirs/madams will be able to set me on the right track!

So I conducted an online survey experiment. I'll outline the conditions and participant allocation procedures below:

Participants were initially randomly allocated to one of 4 conditions: a hierarchy-egalitarianism control condition, an individualism-communitarinaism control condition, a hierarchy-egalitarianism experimental condition and an individualism-communitarianism experimental condition.

In both the control and experimental hierarchy-egalitarianism conditions, participants completed a scale designed to measure their cultural values along this dimension. In the control and experimental individualism-communitarianism conditions, they completed a different scale designed to measure their cultural values along this dimension.

In both *experimental* conditions, scores on these scales were then calculated by the survey software in real time, immediately afterwhich participants were administered a particular experimental manipulation determined by whether they scored above or below the mid-point on the scale they completed.

So for instance, a participant in the experimental hierarchy-egalitarianism condition who scored above the mid-point on the hierarchy-egalitarianism scale was designated as a hierarchist, and exposed to a distinct experimental manipulation designed to make them *even more* hierarchical in outlook. In contrast, a participant scoring below the midpoint on the hierarchy-egalitarianism scale in this condition was designated an egalitarian, and as a result received a distinct manipulation designed to increase their egalitarianism yet further. The equivalent was true in the experimental individualism-communitarianism condition. Therefore, there were two experimental conditions to which participants were randomly assigned, each of which was then itself split into two conditions on the basis of participants cultural/ ideological outlook on the relevant dimension. This yielded four experiment conditions in total:

- experimental hierarchy
- experimental egalitarianism
- experimental individualism
- experimental communitarianism

No experimental manipulation was administered in the control conditions (obviously). However, there were two versions of the control condition, one in which participants completed the hierarchy-egalitarianism scale before seeing a control text, and one in which they completed the individualism-communitarianism scale. Allocation to control condition was completely random at this stage. Thus, in term of participant *experience*, control conditions were:

- Control hierarchy-egalitarianism
- Control individualism-communitarianism

However, for *analytic* purposes, participants in each control condition were further split into two "sub-conditions" to generate a control pairing for each experimental condition. Thus, according to the same criteria (i.e. scores above or below the midpoint on the relevant scale) which determined how participants were split in the experimental conditions, the control hierarchy-egalitarianism  was split into control hierarchy and control egalitarianism, and control individualism-communitarianism was split into control individualism and control hierarchy. Thus, from an analytic perspective, there were 8 conditions in total. control conditions were:

- control hierarchy
- control egalitarianism
- control individualism
- control communitarianism
- experimental hierarchy
- experimental egalitarianism
- experimental individualism
- experimental communitarianism

This left me with control and experimental condition pairs with which to perform between-subjects comparisons e.g. control hierarchy and experimental hierarchy.

Obviously, allocation to condition was part random and part based on participant characteristics.

**So my question is, does anyone know how to describe this experimental design formally?**

I'm thinking I have two IVs, one being the scale which participants completed and one being weather they received the control or experimental treatment.

Perhaps some hybrid between an experimental and quasi-experimental design?

I'm really not clear on the design, and I'm confusing myself reading about factorial nested designs, which may or may not be relevant!

I'm also not sure whether sample splitting for analytic purposes should be considered part of the design or not.

Any advice anyone might be able to give would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: How much work did you put into this without an analysis plan? How many people were subjected to an experiment that might not be usable? Was it wise, ethical, or useful to conduct this experiment without a plan for statistical analysis before you started?

Comment: Wise? Definitely not. I hope to learn from the experience.
Ethical? I don't think what I did presents any serious ethical issues. Participants gave 15 mins of their time max in exchange for course credit. No harm came to them.
Useful? Yes. I've analysed the data and generated results which speak to my hypotheses. Probably not optimally, but definitely sufficiently to say I have findings that support or fail to support each of my hypotheses. My issue is not that I fail to understand the logic of the experiment and how that relates to analysis, more technical language in experimental design.

Comment: Usually an analysis requires a careful description of an experiment and vice-versa. You could describe what analysis you did. As far as ethics goes, an experiment without a satisfactory analysis, positive or negative, is pointless, and therefore unethical, since it subjects people or animals to worthless activity, even if the risks are very small. In other words, every planned experiment should have an adequate analysis plan before collecting data.

Comment: OK, consider your rebuke gratefully accepted. I conducted multiple analyses but the main ones were between-subjects comparisons between control and experiment condition pairs (i.e. control and experimental egalitarianism). Manipulations were intended to strengthen participants' existing cultural orientations e.g. an egalitarian in the experimental egalitarianism condition was exposed to a text designed to increase their egalitarianism, while in the control condition they were exposed to a neutral text). I then conducted manipulation checks to see whether post-manipulation scores on my (1)

Comment: hierarchy-egalitarianism or individualism-communitarianism scale (depending on condition) differed significantly between the control and experimental conditions for any given pairing. I then looked to see whether any effect of condition emerged for my risk perception DVs e.g. whether experimental egalitarians rated climate change as more risky than control egalitarians. I also did several multivariate regression analyses using pre-manipulation hierarchy-egal / individualism-communitarianism scores as predictor variables (among others). Lots of analyses -- too much to fully detail -- sorry.